# не отправляется пакет icmp

Tags: linux, c

Столько времени провозился. Вроде бы всё нормально, я не могу найти ошибку. wireshark не фиксирует этот пакет. Когда то давно писал нечто подобное, ну делал пакет и wireshark фиксировал ( тогда у меня была проблема с checksum ). Но тогда я может не делал пакет прям с нуля. Но всё же я могу по идее указать любой мак и отправить в сеть. А блин. Возможно мне надо отправлять через интерфейс. А блин посмотрел документацию man packet. Ещё проверил функцию write, она действительно возвращает ошибку, то есть пакет собран вроде нормально. Я так понял для отправки пакета нужно заполнить структуру struct sockaddr_ll. Но я не помню как это сделать. Думаю она должна быть первой в буфере, который я отправлю. Странно, я хотя английский не очень хорошо знаю, но вроде написано что эта структура sockaddr_ll это адрес физического слоя. Фиг знает. Врядли это передастся по сети, скорее это надо для ядра линукса. Я конечно попробую щас поставить эту структуру первой, но у меня может не получиться. И вдруг в коде у меня есть другие ошибки. Так что выкладываю код. Вообще я делаю систему обнаружения вторжений. А эта утилита, этот модуль, когда я доведу до конца, добавлю в утилиту. Она будет воспроизводить правила snort для атаки на хост. И моя система обнаружения должна все атаки задетектировать.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/ether.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "packet.h"

int sockfd;
#define SOURCE_IP_HACKER  "192.168.1.2"
#define MAIN_COMPUTER "1c:6f:65:8b:0d:f5"
#define NETBOOK "54:04:a6:34:f0:b6"

void init ( )
{
    sockfd = socket ( AF_PACKET, SOCK_PACKET, htons ( ETH_P_ALL ) );
    if ( sockfd == -1 ) {
        perror ( "socket" );
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}

unsigned char get_random ( )
{
    unsigned char a = rand ( ) % 256;
    return a;
}

void set_random_mac ( char *packet )
{
    struct ethhdr *eth = ( struct ethhdr * ) packet;
    unsigned char *e = &eth->h_source[0];
    for ( int i = 0; i < ETH_ALEN; i++, e++ ) *e = get_random ( ); 
}

void set_main_mac ( char *packet )
{
    struct ether_addr *ea = ether_aton ( MAIN_COMPUTER );
    if ( !ea ) {
        perror ( "ether_aton" );
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    struct ethhdr *eth = ( struct ethhdr * ) packet;
    for ( int i = 0; i < ETH_ALEN; i++ ) {
        eth->h_source[i] = ea->ether_addr_octet[i];
    }
}

void rand_init ( )
{
    srandom ( time ( NULL ) );
}

void set_ether_destination ( char *packet, const char *mac )
{
    struct ether_addr *ea = ether_aton ( mac );
    if ( !ea ) {
        perror ( "ether_aton" );
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    struct ethhdr *eth = ( struct ethhdr * ) packet;
    for ( int i = 0; i < ETH_ALEN; i++ ) {
        eth->h_dest[i] = ea->ether_addr_octet[i];
    }
}

void set_ether_type ( char *packet, const unsigned short type )
{
    struct ethhdr *eth = ( struct ethhdr * ) packet;
    eth->h_proto = type;
}

unsigned short checksum ( unsigned short *addr, int len )
{
    unsigned short result;
    unsigned int sum = 0;

    while ( len > 1 ) {
        sum += *addr++;
        len -= 2;
    }

    if ( len == 1 ) sum += *( unsigned char * ) addr;

    sum = ( sum >> 16 ) + ( sum & 0xffff );
    sum += ( sum >> 16 );
    result = ~sum;
    return result;
}

void set_ip_id ( char *packet, int id )
{
    struct ip *ip = ( struct ip * ) ( sizeof ( struct ethhdr ) + packet );
    ip->ip_id = id;
}

void set_ip_addr ( char *packet, const char *source, const char *dest )
{
    struct sockaddr_in s, d;
    inet_aton ( source, &s.sin_addr );
    inet_aton ( dest, &d.sin_addr );

    struct ip *ip = ( struct ip * ) ( sizeof ( struct ethhdr ) + packet );

    memcpy ( &ip->ip_src, &s.sin_addr, sizeof ( s ) );
    memcpy ( &ip->ip_dst, &d.sin_addr, sizeof ( d ) );
}

void set_ip_version ( char *packet, const unsigned int version )
{
    struct ip *ip = ( struct ip * ) ( sizeof ( struct ethhdr ) + packet );
    ip->ip_v = version;
}

void set_ip_header_size ( char *packet, const unsigned int size )
{
    struct ip *ip = ( struct ip * ) ( sizeof ( struct ethhdr ) + packet );
    ip->ip_hl = size;
}

void set_ip_protocol ( char *packet, const short proto )
{
    struct ip *ip = ( struct ip * ) ( sizeof ( struct ethhdr ) + packet );
    ip->ip_p = proto;
}

void set_ip_tos ( char *packet, unsigned char tos )
{
    struct ip *ip = ( struct ip * ) ( sizeof ( struct ethhdr ) + packet );
    ip->ip_tos |= tos;
}

void set_ip_ttl ( char *packet, unsigned char ttl )
{
    struct ip *ip = ( struct ip * ) ( sizeof ( struct ethhdr ) + packet );
    ip->ip_ttl = ttl;
}

void set_ip_total_length ( char *packet, size_t total_length )
{
    struct ip *ip = ( struct ip * ) ( sizeof ( struct ethhdr ) + packet );
    ip->ip_len = total_length;
}

void set_ip_fragment_off ( char *packet, unsigned short off )
{
    struct ip *ip = ( struct ip * ) ( sizeof ( struct ethhdr ) + packet );
    ip->ip_off = off;
}

void set_ip_checksum ( char *packet )
{
    struct ip *ip = ( struct ip * ) ( sizeof ( struct ethhdr ) + packet );
    ip->ip_sum = checksum ( ( unsigned short * ) ip, sizeof ( struct ip ) );
}

int get_icmp_length ( )
{
    return sizeof ( struct icmp ) + 56;
}

void set_icmp_type ( char *packet, int type )
{
    struct icmp *icmp = ( struct icmp * ) ( sizeof ( struct ethhdr ) + sizeof ( struct ip ) + packet );
    icmp->icmp_type = type;
}

void set_icmp_code ( char *packet, int code )
{
    struct icmp *icmp = ( struct icmp * ) ( sizeof ( struct ethhdr ) + sizeof ( struct ip ) + packet );
    icmp->icmp_code = code;
}

void set_icmp_checksum ( char *packet )
{
    struct icmp *icmp = ( struct icmp * ) ( sizeof ( struct ethhdr ) + sizeof ( struct ip ) + packet );
    icmp->icmp_cksum = checksum ( ( unsigned short * ) icmp, sizeof ( struct icmp ) + 56 );
}

void set_icmp_data ( char *packet )
{
    struct icmp *icmp = ( struct icmp * ) ( sizeof ( struct ethhdr ) + sizeof ( struct ip ) + packet );
    gettimeofday ( ( struct timeval * ) icmp->icmp_data, NULL );
}

int set_icmp_packet ( char *packet, const char *mac, const char *ip )
{
    //set_random_mac ( packet );
    set_main_mac ( packet );
    set_ether_destination ( packet, mac );
    set_ether_type ( packet, ETHERTYPE_IP );

    set_ip_addr ( packet, SOURCE_IP_HACKER, ip );
    set_ip_header_size ( packet, sizeof ( struct ip ) );
    set_ip_version ( packet, 4 );
    set_ip_protocol ( packet, IPPROTO_ICMP );
    set_ip_tos ( packet, 0 ); // 1 << 5
    set_ip_ttl ( packet, 64 );
    set_ip_total_length ( packet, get_icmp_length ( ) );
    set_ip_fragment_off ( packet, 0 );
    set_ip_id ( packet, getpid ( ) );
    set_ip_checksum ( packet );

    set_icmp_type ( packet, ICMP_ECHO );
    set_icmp_code ( packet, 0 );
    set_icmp_data ( packet );
    set_icmp_checksum ( packet );

    return sizeof ( struct ethhdr ) + sizeof ( struct ip ) + get_icmp_length ( ); // return size of packet
}


int main ( )
{
    char buf[ETH_FRAME_LEN];
    memset ( &buf[0], 0, ETH_FRAME_LEN );

    rand_init ( );
    init ( );

    int length_of_packet_icmp = set_icmp_packet ( &buf[0], NETBOOK, "192.168.1.3" );

    int ret = write ( sockfd, buf, length_of_packet_icmp );
    if ( ret == -1 ) {
        perror ( "write" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Если память не изменяет, то отправлять ICMP-пакеты в Linux можно только если у вас приложение запущено от суперпользователя (sudo или setuid) или если есть разрешение cap_net_raw

Comment: Да я уже смог отправить пакеты, надо было вместо SOCK_PACKET написать SOCK_RAW и вроде ещё пару изменений. Теперь отправляет пакет, но в wireshark ругается что нет fcs в конце кадра или фрейма.